# Error: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I found a lot of posts about the same problem but none could help. Can you please help me figure out why I am getting this error? I am using: `IEEEtran.bst` and `IEEEtran.cls`. Both of those files and the main .tex file and the `references.bib` are in one folder. When I try to compile my script, I get this error:

```
test.bbl(24): Error: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

Here is `test.bbl`:

```
% Generated by IEEEtran.bst, version: 1.12 (2007/01/11)
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{#1}
\csname url@samestyle\endcsname
\providecommand{\newblock}{\relax}
\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
\providecommand{\BIBentrySTDinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=0pt\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor}{4}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus
\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor\fontdimen3\font minus
  \fontdimen4\font\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBforeignlanguage}[2]{{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\relax
\typeout{** WARNING: IEEEtran.bst: No hyphenation pattern has been}%
\typeout{** loaded for the language `#1'. Using the pattern for}%
\typeout{** the default language instead.}%
\else
\language=\csname l@#1\endcsname
\fi
#2}}
\providecommand{\BIBdecl}{\relax}
\BIBdecl

\end{thebibliography}
```

And my test.tex:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\section{Test Citation}
\cite{logjam2015}

% ---- Bibliography ----
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

And the references.bib

```
@inproceedings{logjam2015,
 author               = {Adrian, David and Bhargavan, Karthikeyan and Durumeric, Zakir and Gaudry, Pierrick and Green, Matthew and Halderman, J. Alex and Heninger, Nadia and Springall, Drew and Thom{\'e}, Emmanuel and Valenta, Luke and VanderSloot, Benjamin and Wustrow, Eric and Zanella-B{\'e}guelin, Santiago and Zimmermann, Paul},
 booktitle            = {Proceedings of the 22nd ACM SIGSAC Conference on Computer and Communications Security (CCS '15)},
 pages                = {5-17},
 title                = {{I}mperfect {F}orward {S}ecrecy: {H}ow {D}iffie-{H}ellman {F}ails in {P}ractice},
 url                  = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2810103.2813707},
 year                 = {2015},
 }
```

Comment: Your `bbl` file has no `\bibitem`. Regenerate it running BibTeX; you need at least one `\cite` (or `\nocite`) command in your document.

Comment: 0
down vote
There is no point in trying to fix this as the reason this is happening is because the IEEE website gives you a template with an old IEEEtran.bst file. Please update it from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex

Comment: I had similar problems -- which says "LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \ite m." in Revtex -- but somehow in my case, I need to remove \center in the \begin{figure} ...\end{figure}

Comment: @egreg
 you saved my life!

Answer (score 58):

You have generated the `.bbl` file at a time when your document contained no `\cite` or `\nocite` command. The error derives from a bad redefinition made by `IEEEtran.cls` of the `\endthebibliography` macro.

The standard classes have something like

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {[irrelevant code omitted]}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```

which implies

```
\def\endthebibliography{%
  \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist
}
```

but `IEEEtran.cls` has

```
\let\endthebibliography\endlist
```

which is plainly wrong.

If you fix it

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
\def\endthebibliography{%
  \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Citation}
\cite{logjam2015}

% ---- Bibliography ----
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

then also an empty `.bbl` file (that is, with no `\bibitem` command) will just produce a warning and not an error.

Comment: this saved my sanity while on a deadline for a paper submission :)

Comment: @meetaig You're welcome!

Comment: Note it could also happen when using software and not compiling by yourself when compiling the wrong tex (e.g. supplementary) that has no citations

Comment: Genius! I was searching around for more than 1 hour.. I am pretty  new in LaTex/Overleaf

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I am using resume.cls and I did what you suggested but I still get errors: 

Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{A}
Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{B}

Comment: @QGravity Sorry, but with a different class the problem might be in some other place. Please, open a new question with the details of your setup.

Answer (score 14):

In case the error keeps presenting even you already added a `\cite{something}` in your paper, then you have to clear the auxiliary files.

In details, **delete any files ended with `.log .aux .bbl .blg`**. Then compile the document again and voila.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem that i have + i was citing the wrong key

Comment: Worked for me too. Did not do the things at answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350921/45967

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same error message, with an empty `.bbl` file. If you are using MiKTeX like me, you can try to change `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` with `\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}` with all lower case. Then run BibTeX. Finally generate your document running what you are used to. It solved my problem.

I found this solution reading https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran, where they provide the latest version of the IEEEtran BibTeX style (which I didn't need to download by the way), and specified that it is contained in TeX Live as IEEE­tran and in **MiKTeX as ieee­tran**.

Comment: I was searching for the solution to this more than 30 minutes, thx!

Answer (score 4):

For me, there was no content in the latex files so by just including a temporary citation in the paper solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this was in the context of a BibTex BBL file, which, upon inspection was empty.

Apparently, Overleaf reported the .bib file's name as `Mendeley.bib` and I included `\bibliography{Mendeley}`, but the file was silently not found.

**Solution:** I renamed the .bib file to all lower case and updated the `\bibliography` entry to match and everything worked as expected.