# resume.cls, BibTex, and "Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{...}" Error

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, resume, bibentry

I am using [resume.cls](https://github.com/treyhunner/resume/find/master) for making a CV and I would like to make a list of publications using BibTeX. I have already used the suggestions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297365/how-to-use-bibtex-for-putting-a-nice-publication-list-in-resume-with-document-cl) (the answer by @jak123) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350907/error-latex-error-somethings-wrong-perhaps-a-missing-item/350921?noredirect=1#comment1441611_350921) (the answer by @egreg) on how to use BibTex to generate a list of publication and it seems that it works and generates a file with a complete list of publication. The code is

```
\documentclass{resume} 
\usepackage{bibentry}

\makeatletter
\def\endthebibliography{%
\def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
\endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nobibliography{cv}
\bibliographystyle{JHEP}

 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 %  Publication
 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Publications}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \bibentry{A1}
\item \bibentry{A2}
\item \bibentry{A3}
\end{enumerate}

\end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

However, the following error shows up

```
Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{A1}
Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{A2}
Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{A3}
```

Is there a way to get rid of this error since it is quite annoying?

Comment: This `resume.cls` has the same problem as the `res.cls` discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27139/35864. It issues `\nofiles` and stops aux file writing, which means that BibTeX can't work. You can try the fix suggested in the link, but maybe this should be a reason to think about whether or not this `resume.cls` is what you should be using. It doesn't appear to be very actively maintained and does some dangerous stuff (`\renewcommand{\document}`). The usage hint at the top of the file `\documentstyle{resume}` also has me worried.

Comment: Note that in your MWE you are missing the `\bibliographystyle` call and `bibentry`'s `\nobibliography` call.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the commnets. The point is that I get the perfect pdf which does contain all the information but I get this error and it is very annoying. I also corrected the MWE.