# Getting the error "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. ...}<section title>}{1}{section.1}". What should I do?

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, sectioning, texstudio, subsection

I am new to LateX and have started to like it very much. I have a document which on compilation gives the error as stated in the question. I am working with TexStudio and when I click on the error message, *.toc file is opened and it shows the following on the corresponding line:

`\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}<subsection title>}{1}{subsection.1.1}%`

An answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350907/error-latex-error-somethings-wrong-perhaps-a-missing-item) says it could be since I have used bibliography and haven't cited anything. I have already cited some sources. Another [solution](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/LaTeX_Error%3A_Something%27s_wrong--perhaps_a_missing_%5Citem) provided by Overleaf suggests missing `\item`. I don't have any lists in the document yet. My code is given below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{cit.bib}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
linkcolor = black,
urlcolor  = blue,
citecolor = blue,
anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\title{Document Title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{July 2022}
\usepackage{titling}
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\null\mbox{}\vfill}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookd{\vfill\null}

\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{(\oldref{#1})}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for adding header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\lhead{Some Text}
\rhead{some More Text}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlingpage}
        
        \maketitle
        
    \end{titlingpage}

    \newpage
    
        \tableofcontents
        
    \newpage
    
        \listoffigures
        
    \newpage
        
        \section{Section Title}
        \label{sec:ex1}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        
            \subsection{Subsection Title}
            \label{sec:ex1a}
            Some text ... \autocite{BAuthor} ... Further more text, which I think maybe irrelevant 
            to the question.
    \newpage
            \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should show an example that really exhibits the error. Copy the code in a new document in some test folder and test it before posting. If a citation is needed to show the error replace the bib by `biblatex-examples.bib`  and cite e.g `doody`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have tested this for error and it persists. However, I have found a solution, which I have added as answer here. Thank you for the input.

Comment: I tested it too and I get no error. Also nowhere in the document is the text `section heading` from your error message. So sorry but my claims stays that you didn't show the real state of your document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, The ```section heading``` was supposed to be the placeholder. I forgot that and ended up using ```section title``` instead. I tried again with this code after your latest comment and still have the error. Anyway the problem was resolved as I mentioned in the answer. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond to the question.

Comment: if your code above errors if you compile it (unchanged!) in some empty folder then you should show your log-file as then something is wrong in your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out what went wrong. I moved `\pagenumbering{arabic}` from after section title to immediately after `\newpage`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: There is nothing in the definition of \pagenumbering to trigger such an error. You probably simply recompiled and corrected some auxiliary files.